# Configure Jenkins Mac OS X native package to run in a different port

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins native Mac OS package installs by default in `/Users/Shared/Jenkins` and the war in `/Applications/Jenkins`. It runs as a daemon and restarts automatically in spite of a `kill -9` command.

I added a `winstone.properties` in `/Applications/Jenkins` with a single prop, `httpPort=9999`.

Still app starts on 8080.

I even installed CLI and tried:

```
    java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://127.0.0.1:8080/ shutdown

Failed to authenticate with your SSH keys. Proceeding with anonymous access
Sep 19, 2011 1:11:00 PM hudson.remoting.Channel$ReaderThread run
SEVERE: I/O error in channel CLI connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080/
java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$ReaderThread.run(Channel.java:1093)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2553)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1296)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$ReaderThread.run(Channel.java:1087)
Exception in thread "main" hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the 
channel
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:149)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:681)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:158)
    at $Proxy2.main(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.cli.CLI.execute(CLI.java:171)
    at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:297)
    at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:216)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:273)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:732)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$ReaderThread.run(Channel.java:1117)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$ReaderThread.run(Channel.java:1093)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2553)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1296)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$ReaderThread.run(Channel.java:1087)
```

In short, I can't force stop/start Jenkins and/or configure (I can via manual procedure, using a war though).

Suggestions?
Any idea how to configure the Jenkins

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci httpPort '9999'
```

To check that it has worked use:

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci
```

Then kill the Jenkins process and let it restart.

Answer (score 9):

You want to use `launchctl` to start and stop Jenkins.  From the example at [luscarpa.com: Start & Stop Jenkins daemon on Mac OS X](http://www.luscarpa.com/snippets/jenkins/start-stop-jenkins-daemon-on-mac-os-x/):

Start Jenkins:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Stop Jenkins:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Answer (score 3):

For those new to *killing processes* (like I am):

```
$ ps -e | grep jenkins
   53 ??         0:02.51 /usr/bin/java -jar /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war
  392 ttys000    0:00.00 grep jenkins

$ sudo kill 53
```

Comment: For platforms that have it, you can use "pkill" to do this process in one step.  I have recently been doing a lot of `pkill -9 java` commands, because we tightened up our tomcat configuration to eliminate the shutdown port, and now the only way to get it to shut down is to send it a signal.